# html5 web audio recording: is input source selection possible?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, recording

Please take a look at this web audio recording example by Chris Wilson:
http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Here the default browser behaviour is asking the user permission, if granted audio gets captured. However there is no information about the input source. I guess it's defaults to the microphone.

**Is it possible to give the user a prompt for selecting the desired input (for someone who has a fancy/professional sound card with many input channels) before recording audio with html5?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot know or set the audio input or output with client-side javascript.

Comment: That's a shame... Thanks.